# Clicking on an image to download it, rather than opening up a new tab?

Tags: jquery

I have a image thumbnail, and when someone clicks it, it should download it to your computer instead of opening in new tab/window. Is this possible? I don't want to use the HTML5 attribute `download` to accomplish this. Would like to know if it's possbile w/ jQuery.

```
HTML:

<a class="dl" href="//placehold.it/650x350">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x150">
    <span>Click to Download</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `download` attribute?

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery File Download Plugin](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx). You can use this in the `.click()` handler.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the plugin suggestion, will definitely keep that one for another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is simply using the `download` attribute inside the `a` tag. However, it's possible to set the attribute using either JavaScript or jQuery.

In jQuery, we can either use the `prop` or `attr` methods, which acts as both a setter and getter. To set the property, we pass a string in as part of the second parameter name.

jQuery example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").parent().prop("download", "filename.jpg");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u5shchm/

In JavaScript, we use the `setAttribute` function.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dl")[0].setAttribute("download", filename.jpg");
```

Fiddle Link

https://jsfiddle.net/Lff6erj1/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use "[download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)".

EXAMPLE: `<a src="xyz" download>Click to Download</a>`:

Comment: He wrote: "I don't want to use the HTML5 attribute `download` to accomplish this."